# Getting maximum value from table using LINQ

Tags: sql-server, database, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a table in my database. I want to get the maximum value of a column named NumOfView. I used this code:

```
var advert=(from ad in storedb.Ads
             where ad.AdScope == "1" 
             select ad.NumOfView).Max();
```

It works but when there are two or more same maximum values it doesn't work and this message appears:

> Sequence contains more than one element

What should I do now? Your answers will be very helpfull. Thanks

Comment: Where does that message "appear"? If it's part of an exception, please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
 var advert = storedb.ads
                    .Where(a => a.AdScope == "1")
                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.NumOfView)
                    .First();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var advert = storedb.ads
                    .Where(a => a.AdScope == "1")
                    .Select(a => a.NumOfView)
                    .Max()
                    .first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see one example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<int> lista = new List<int>();
    lista.Add(1);
    lista.Add(2);
    lista.Add(2);
    lista.Add(3);
    lista.Add(3);
    var query = (from lt in lista
                 orderby lt descending
                 select lt).FirstOrDefault<int>();
    textBox1.Text = query.ToString();

}
```